# Geany text editor doesn't highlight codes anymore

Tags: colors, syntax-highlighting, geany

Yesterday I wrote a simple python program using Geany and it worked just right, today when I went to write another program, I received `error 9009` and the editor didn't highlight any words, they were all colored as variables (e.g print, while, int, input and ...).

I did a bit of research and ultimately fixed `error 9009` and managed to run my program but Geany still doesn't highlight my code, and when I execute my other programs they're all also non-highlighted and give me error code `2`.

To fix the `error 9009` I changed the `Execute` command in `Set Build Commands` to `Python %f` and it worked, I tried deleting and reinstalling Geany for the greyed out text, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Greyed out codes:
[image: Greyed out codes]

Error code `2` for programs before this happened:
[image: Error code 2 for programs before this happened]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it as `.py` at the end (or whatever language you're using it for, for example, Python is `.py`), then the syntax highlighting will happen.